# filter and count without summarizing the data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame and I want to filter the rows by a certain number of appearances of certain criteria.

Example:

```
yelp_tbl_asian %>% count(name) %>% filter(n > 10)

# A tibble: 16 x 2
                 name     n
                <chr> <int>
 1       China Buffet    12
 2       China Garden    12
 3        China House    14
 4         China Star    13
```

After that step, I want to filter/edit the data frame by other criteria.

Example:

```
yelp_tbl_asian %>% filter(rating > 3.5) %>% select(attributes) %>% dmap(unlist) %>% count(attributes) %>% arrange(desc(n))

# A tibble: 227 x 2
                         attributes     n
                              <chr> <int>
 1         RestaurantsTakeOut: True  3265
 2        RestaurantsAttire: casual  3233
 3                GoodForKids: True  2986
 4 BusinessAcceptsCreditCards: True  2939
```

The problem is, that the first step is eliminating the following criteria from the data set. So after the first filtering, the second step isn´t possible anymore. I want to combine both commands/steps.

Comment: Maybe use `left_join` after `filter()` to merge it with the original df on `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, you could proceed with a merge. I prefer avoiding this and use the `group_by`+`mutate` combo that avoids your table to be summarized and simply adds a column with the count per name (repeated as many times as there are observations):

```
yelp_tbl_asian %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(n=n()) %>% filter(n > 10)
```

Then you can continue your pipe by adding more filters for your second step.